# Why can't I update a Dictionary Key:Value pair that has nil as the value?

Tags: swift

In the Following code:

```
var dict1: [String:Int?] = ["Blue" : 1, "Red" : nil]
let a: Int? = dict1.updateValue(2, forKey: "Red")
```

I get the error:

```
"cannot convert value of type 'Int??' to specified type 'Int?'
```

1. What does Int?? mean?
2. What's the proper way to update Dictionaries if the target pair has a nil value?

Comment: `nil`s in dictionaries mostly do not make sense since `nil` is normally signaling the absence of an associated value. Omitting the entry for "Red" will behave as expected. `Int??` is a double optional, you get it because reading a value from the dictionary always gets you an optional and since the type inside is itself an optional you get double optionals.

Comment: Adding to @luk2302 - why are you declaring a dictionary key with nil? Sure, it may take a few lines of code to - down the road processing - check for that key to exist, but isn't that a much safer way to code things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question mark is because your dictionary's values are Int?.  The second question mark is because your call to updateValue returns an optional wrapping one of your dictionary's values.  Thus a Int??